# Signal when value is changed ( before return) of a field of a EnhTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, signals-slots

I have a question concerning signals of a field of a EnhTableWidget:

- when I **click into a cell** of that table  -->
  ..**currentCellChanged(int,int,int,int)** is emitted
- when I **click return** in a cell of a table  --> 
  ..**cellChanged(int,int)** is emitted

I need to start a calculation-method when the value of a cell is changed, but **before** return is pressed.Is there a signal for that, something like

when I **change the value of a field ( no return yet !)** of that table  --> ..**??** is emitted

Comment: What is EnhTableWidget?

Answer (score 2):

Create a customized delegate that handles changes emitted by the cell editor:

```
MyDelegate::MyDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget* MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // Assume you want a QLineEdit editor for the QTableWidget cell
    QLineEdit* editor = new QLineEdit(parent);

    // Get notified when editor changes
    QObject::connect(editor, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, [=](const QString &newValue) {
        qDebug() << "Cell has changed without pressing return: " << newValue;
    }

    return editor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [itemChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal is emitted

```
void QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem * item)
```

Also you could try to catch the [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal, which is inherited from the QAbstractItemView class

```
void QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> & roles = QVector<int> ())
```

Or you could subclass QTableWidget and reimplement [keyPressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) or use [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) with a custom keyPressHandler if you don't want to subclass:

```
tableWidget->installEventFilter(keyPressHandler);
```

Comment: In my code the itemChanged signal is emitted only after I pressed return. But I want a signal emitted BEFORE pressing return ( in order be sure that the last user-Input is taken into account even if the user leaves the table without pressing return)

Comment: Updated my above answer